# R - rbind converting num value to chr in dataframe

Tags: r, rbind

The addition of a row to a dataframe using rbind, seems to be converting salary to a chr type?

```
id = 1:10
dept = c("Engineering", "Operations", "Compliance", "Engineering","Operations",
        "Operations", "Compliance", "Sales", "HR", "HR"
        )
name = c("Stephen", "Mary", "Frank", "Nick", "Joseph",
         "Felicity", "Jim", "Rachel", "Fiona", "Jack")

salary = c(50000,100000,25000,40000,80000,
          70000, 60000, 125000, 105000, 200000)

emp <- data.frame(id, dept, name, salary, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
str(emp)  # salary is a num
new_emp = c(id=11, dept="Human Resources", name="Jeremy", salary=53000)
emp <- rbind(emp, new_emp)
str(emp)  # conversion to a chr type for salary?
```

Initial str():

```
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ id    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ dept  : chr  "Engineering" "Operations" "Compliance" "Engineering" ...
 $ name  : chr  "Stephen" "Mary" "Frank" "Nick" ...
 $ salary: num  50000 100000 25000 40000 80000 70000 60000 125000 105000 200000
```

After adding a row using rbind:

```
'data.frame':   11 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ id    : chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ dept  : chr  "Engineering" "Operations" "Compliance" "Engineering" ...
 $ name  : chr  "Stephen" "Mary" "Frank" "Nick" ...
 $ salary: chr  "50000" "1e+05" "25000" "40000" ...
```

Comment: `new_emp` is a vector which has only one type. Change `c(id=11, dept="Human Resources", name="Jeremy", salary=53000)` into `data.frame(id=11, dept="Human Resources", name="Jeremy", salary=53000)` to get your desired result.

Comment: thanks, would a list have worked?

Comment: Just try it. ;-)

Comment: @MartinGal well knock me down with a feather, it worked....

Comment: @MartinGal if you add it as a formal answer I will accept it